# MySQL - Deleting rows based on column subset duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, subset, sql-delete

I have a table containing roughly 5 million rows and 150 columns. However, there are several similar rows that I would like to consider duplicates if they share the same values for 3 columns : `ID`, `Order` and `Name`.

However, I don't just want to delete the duplicates at random, I want the row I consider a duplicate to be the one which has the smaller count value (`Count` being another column) or if they have the same count, then base it on which has the earliest date column (`Date` is another column).

I have tried with the code below:

```
    DELETE t1 FROM uploaddata_copy t1
  JOIN uploaddata_copy t2
  ON t2.Name = t1.Name
  AND t2.ID = t1.ID
  AND t2.Order = t1.Order
  AND t2.Count < t1.Count
  AND t2.Date < t1.Date
```

However (and this is probably due to my computer) it seems to run indefinitely (~25mins) before timing out from the server so I'm left unsure if this is correct and I just need to run for even longer or if the code is inherently wrong and there is a quicker way of doing it.

Comment: your query seems ok, did you try a select before ?

Comment: Well that's somewhat encouraging, no I didn't try a `SELECT` statement, could you expand on how that would look?

Comment: On a sidenote: Only call a column `ID` when it's the ID of the table, uniquely identifying a record in it. This is obviously not the case in your table.

Comment: These are just dummy names for the columns, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your comparisions seem wrong. You say you want to delete duplicates and you consider a duplicate a record with the same name + id + order and a smaller count. You delete from t1 where `t2.Count < t1.Count`. Shouldn't this be vice versa `t2.Count > t1.Count`? Another point: You join a t1 with probably multiple t2 (in case there are several duplicates for one name + id + order); so you tell the DBMS to delete a t1 multiple times. Probably something the DBMS will handle, it just doesn't look proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more accurate query would be:

```
DELETE t1
    FROM uploaddata_copy t1 JOIN
         uploaddata_copy t2
         ON t2.Name = t1.Name AND
            t2.ID = t1.ID AND
            t2.Order = t1.Order AND
            (t2.Count < t1.Count OR
             t2.Count = t1.Count AND t2.Date < t1.Date
            );
```

However, fixing the logic will not (in this case) improve performance.  First, you want an index on `uploaddata_copy(Name, Id, Order, Count, Date)`.  This allows the "lookup" to be between the original data and only the index.

Second, start small.  Add a `LIMIT 1` or `LIMIT 10` to see how long it takes to remove just a few rows.  Deleting rows is a complicated process, because it affects the table, indexes, and the transaction log -- not to mention any triggers on the table.

If a lot of rows are being deleted, you might find it faster to re-create the table, but that depends heavily on the relative number of rows being removed.

Comment: Could I follow up on this and ask how I would alter this code to now only drop duplicates where I consider the duplicates to be any rows that share the same ID, Order & Count? I tried just doing: `DELETE t1
    FROM uploaddata_copy t1 JOIN
         uploaddata_copy t2
         ON t2.Name = t1.Name AND
            t2.ID = t1.ID AND
            t2.Order = t1.Order` But unfortunately that deleted all but 4 rows out of 5 million...

Comment: @Matt . . . You need to include `count` in the `join` conditions.  If that doesn't help, then ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Why the join? You want to delete rows when there **exists** a "better" record. So use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
delete from dup using uploaddata_copy as dup
where exists
(
  select *
  from uploaddata_copy better
  where better.name = dup.name
    and better.id = dup.id
    and better.order = dup.order
    and (better.count > dup.count or (better.count = dup.count and better.date > dup.date))
);
```

(Please check my comparisions. This is how I understand this: A better record for name + id + order has a greater count or the same count and a higher date. You consider the worse record an undesired duplicate you want to delete.)

You'd have an index on `uploaddata_copy(id, name, order)` at least or better even on `uploaddata_copy(id, name, order, count, date)` for this delete statement to perform well.

Comment: Yes your logic is correct. I've created indexes on the columns you listed, however there seems to be a Syntax error: Unexpected identifier when first referencing the table `uploaddata_copy` on the first line.

Comment: Ah, MySQL doesn't support table alias names in delete. A shame. The syntax in MySQL seems to be `DELETE FROM dup USING uploaddata_copy AS dup` instead. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just found out: an alternative would be `DELETE dup FROM uploaddata_copy AS dup`.

Comment: You can use either exists either a Join.

Comment: @ Daniel E.: Yes, but a join is somewhat blurry here. To select a record with all better records results in the same "bad" record occurring possibly multiple times in the result, where you want to delete it only once of course (as you cannot delete a record multifold). It's much clearer (and possibly faster) to simply check for each record whether at least one better record exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
 DELETE t1 FROM uploaddata_copy t1
  JOIN uploaddata_copy t2
  ON t2.Name = t1.Name
  AND t2.ID = t1.ID
  AND t2.Order = t1.Order
  AND t2.Count < t1.Count
  AND t2.Date < t1.Date
  AND t2.primary_key != t1.primary_key
```